# Node reference field in a webform

Tags: webforms, nodes

Are there any modules available or any procedures available so that node reference fields can be incorporated into a [webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform)?

Comment: A similiar question came up a while ago and I added [an answer which should help you][1]. 


  [1]: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25998/webform-and-node-reference